# Exit inner loop when condition is true

Tags: c, for-loop

I have two arrays of 10 numbers containing random floating numbers between 0 to 1. Let's say `a[10]` and `b[10]`. I am now generating a random floating point number between between 0 and 1 in a variable `c` using the first `for` loop and then comparing it with 'b' in a 2nd `for` loop.

When the condition is true the 2nd `for` loop should stop and go back to the previous `for` loop to generate the next random number. The problem is that I have tried several methods ( increasing k to max limit in if condition or `break` function or `goto` function to exit from 2nd `for` loop when the condition is true but none of them is working correctly and sometimes gives me a garbage value.

It is obvious that the random number will be smaller or equal to the 'b' at some points because both have numbers between 0 to 1.

```
int d;
float e[10];
a={0.3,0.9,1,0.2,0.11,0.21,0.43,0.64,0.55,0.88};

b={0.4,0.7,0.78,0.11,0.49,0.2,0.13,0.74,0.65,0.98};

for (int j=0; j<10; j++) //first for loop for generating random number
    {

        float c=(float)rand()/((float)RAND_MAX);
        for (k=0; k<10; k++) // 2nd for loop for comparison with generated number
        {
            if (c<=b)
            {
                d=k;
                e[k]=a[d];
                printf("%f\n",e);
                k=10;   
                //goto jmp;
                            //break;
            }
        }
        //jmp: printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: you could use 2 pointers to the 2 different functions instead of this, it's less complex to write and handle, more "functional".

Comment: Did you mean `e[j] = a[k]`?

Comment: if (c<=b) this is probably wrong

Comment: That should not even compile! You are comparing a floating point number with a pointer.

Comment: `if (c<=b)` is incorrect because you are comparing a `float` with an `array of float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this condition is wrong:

```
if (c<=b)
```

since your variable declarations are:

```
float c;
float b[10] = {....};
```

So probably you want to do something like

```
   if (c<=b[0])
   {
     ....
     break;
   }
```

Comment: He probably doesn't want to repeatedly compare with only the first element of the array, no.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration for array `a` and `b` of 10 `float`s

```
  a={0.3,0.9,1,0.2,0.11,0.21,0.43,0.64,0.55,0.88};

  b={0.4,0.7,0.78,0.11,0.49,0.2,0.13,0.74,0.65,0.98};
```

is wrong (specially in C). Change this to

```
 float a[10]={0.3,0.9,1,0.2,0.11,0.21,0.43,0.64,0.55,0.88};

 float b[10]={0.4,0.7,0.78,0.11,0.49,0.2,0.13,0.74,0.65,0.98};
```

Now you can't do `if (c<=b)`.`b` is an array of `float` and `c` is a `float` type. No comparison like this is possible in C.
I think you wanted to do this

```
if (c<=b[j]) 
{   
    ....
    printf("%f\n",e[k]);
    ....
}
```

Comment: `(float)rand() % ((float)RAND_MAX);` will result in a value that will almost always be greater than `1`.

Comment: @ajcaruana; True. Removed that part.

Comment: @haccks: I am comparing the c (random value) with the array of float values [b] via for loop so when the condition will be true it will print the the value of a at the index "k". like if the 3rd value is lesser then b[k] then print the a[k].

@ all: Thanks ! I changed my program according to your suggestions and it worked for only 10 numbers with array of 10 numbers , Now I have array of 300 numbers but it's not working for that . At some values it is printing the correct answers and at some values it's printing garbage value

Comment: This might be because there are some mistake in your code or this might be a case of stack overflow for `300` elements.

Comment: I think the code is Ok because I have tried it with lesser numbers array and it's working fine with them.

Comment: if I don't use the break in the for loop then I am not getting garbage values but I am not getting the expected values that means that loop will end will 'j' will be 10 and this causes the change in the values cause there are 2-3 values which will be greater then the random numbers 

There is some problem with break

Comment: Post your complete code [here](http://ideone.com/) then see what I can do for you :)

Comment: @haccks: Thanks
You can check my whole code here 
http://ideone.com/CYFjLR

From line 188 to 205 you can see two for loops, and I am storing the particles value using a function on line 12, and I am using that function on line 54 and 58 line

I am using Microsoft visaula studio 2010 ultimate on windows 7 64 bit and this code is running there without any error

Comment: The reason that ideone giving you error is you are not compiling your code in C99 mode. See the [same code](http://ideone.com/af2TFJ) compiled in C99 mode. The problems are in line 23, 117 and 145. I corrected them.

Comment: @haccks: Thanks I checked my code again there was just the problem with the loop index, I was using the inner loop index 'k'while I need to use the the outer loop index 'j'.

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

By mentioning the name of the array (in your case `e`), it will give you the address. (Array's in some cases decays to pointers)

You have to use e[k] to print the float value.

```
if (c<=b[j])// Here, I have changed it
{        ^-- error was here
    ...
    ...
    printf("%f\n",e[k]);// Here, I have changed it
                  ^-- error was here
```